# how to show {"POWER":"ON"} in else if (this.responseText == ({"POWER":"ON"})) {

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hi all I am trying to get my page to change the button color when I have a response from this.responseText. I know the response I get from Json but I cant get it to allow the response in my code.

If someone could help me that would be great, I have been trying to get this working for sometime, or if you know of a better way to do that I am trying to do please let me know

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            input.MyButton {
                width: 300px;
                padding: 25px;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 150%;
                background: #3366cc;
                color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid white;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding-bottom:25px;
            }
            input.MyButton:hover {
                color: #ffff00;
                background: #000;
                border: 1px solid #fff;
            }
            input.buttonStyle1 {
                 background: red; // or any color you wish
            }
            input.buttonStyle2 {
                 background: green; 
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function togglelight(ipstr) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        console.log(this.responseText); //To check output while error[Optional]
                        alert(this.responseText);
                        if (this.responseText == ({"POWER":"OFF"})) {
                            document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.add("buttonStyle1");
                        } else if (this.responseText == ({"POWER":"ON"})) {
                            document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.add("buttonStyle2");
                        }                 
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.1."+ipstr+"/cm?cmnd=Power%20toggle", true);
                xhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <br>
        <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Office Light" onclick="togglelight('126')" />
        <br>
        <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Fishtank Light" onclick="togglelight('128')" />
        <br>
        <label id ="officestatus">This</label>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert `responseText` into an object, as follows:

```
var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

if (responseObj.POWER === "OFF") {
   document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.add("buttonStyle1");
} else if (responseObj.POWER === "ON") {
   document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.add("buttonStyle2");   
}
```

Here follows a more complete example that uses `id` values on the buttons to toggle them On or Off individually.

It uses a simple helper `StripState()` to assess the status (On/Off) of the clicked button, which then allows us to simulate an AJAX response with the opposite state.

```js
var suffix_on = " On";
var suffix_off = " Off";

function togglelight(ipstr) {
  var button = document.querySelector("#btn_" + ipstr); // get button by its id
  var isOn = StripState(button);
  
  this.responseText = '{ "POWER" : "' + (isOn ? "OFF" : "ON") + '" }';
  console.log(button.id + ' -> ' + this.responseText);
  var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  if (responseObj.POWER === "OFF") {
    button.classList.remove("buttonStyle2");
    button.classList.add("buttonStyle1");
    button.value += suffix_off;
  } else if (responseObj.POWER === "ON") {
    button.classList.remove("buttonStyle1");
    button.classList.add("buttonStyle2");
    button.value += suffix_on;
  }
}

function StripState(btn) {
  var isOn = btn.value.endsWith(suffix_on);
  var isOff = btn.value.endsWith(suffix_off);
  if (isOn || isOff) {
    btn.value = btn.value.substring(0, btn.value.lastIndexOf(' '));
  }
  isOn = !isOff; // in case it contained neither suffix
  return isOn;
}
```

```css
input.buttonStyle1 { background: red;   }
input.buttonStyle2 { background: green; }
```

```html
<input id="btn_126" type="button" value="Office Light" onclick="togglelight('126')" /><br>
<input id="btn_128" type="button" value="Fishtank Light" onclick="togglelight('128')" /><br>
```

Comment: We have a winner sort off it doesnt work all the time for some reason and only wors for the first button not both

Comment: You can of course add further statements into both the `{ ... }` code blocks to also change the button text.

Comment: ok so its only changing one button to green and not doing anything to the 2nd one and wont change the first one to red

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): `document.querySelector returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector`. This means you need to use different selector, best to set unique `id`s on bith buttons and then use those.

Comment: Current code https://codeshare.io/5QYO07

Comment: you lost me peter, so what you showed me will only change the top one to green and not back to red when its off ?

Comment: also i found when it changes to green it stays green and wont go to red

Comment: I added a working example, please see if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (JSON.parse(this.responseText)["POWER"] == "OFF") {
   document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.remove("buttonStyle2");
document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.add("buttonStyle1");
}
else if (JSON.parse(this.responseText)["POWER"] == "ON") {
  document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.remove("buttonStyle1");
document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.add("buttonStyle2");   
}
```

If you want to toggle the color of multiple buttons using the same function, you can pass the reference of the button to the function and then add or remove it's class.

Below is the function

```
function togglelight(btn, ipstr) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if (JSON.parse(this.responseText)["POWER"] == "OFF") {
            btn.classList.remove("buttonStyle2");
            btn.classList.add("buttonStyle1");
        }
        else if (JSON.parse(this.responseText)["POWER"] == "ON") {
            btn.classList.remove("buttonStyle1");
            btn.classList.add("buttonStyle2");   
        }                
     }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.1."+ipstr+"/cm?cmnd=Power%20toggle", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

And HTML

```
<form>
    <br>
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Office Light" onclick="togglelight(this, '126')" />
    <br>
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Fishtank Light" onclick="togglelight(this, '128')" />
    <br>
    <label id ="officestatus">This</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Didnt error but didnt change the button either, as the response text reads {"POWER":"OFF"}

Comment: no sorry mate didnt work atr all

Comment: Try the updated version. Use `JSON.parse` as mentioned in the answer by @Peter B. I've added an extra line to remove unnecessary class.

Comment: OK great thanks so i need to do the same thing for the 2nd button and any other buttons i do , is there a better way to do it

Comment: Updated again. Try it.

Comment: Thanks so much its working great now to make it looks nice :)